# How to install Remix OS with Fedora 24 on a local drive

Tags: fedora, system-installation, grub2, uefi, android

I have a Lenovo Yoga notebook, with a touch screen, but as I am using a Fedora 24 on it, the touch screen became somewhat... untouched (horrible support compared to Windows 10). But instead of installing Windows 10, I figured it would be a better idea to run android on it, preferably Remix OS, and use it for media consumption (MX Player, YouTube).

I've got UEFI only (no legacy bios) with a GPT partition (secure boot is disabled), and I want to have Remix OS on a separate volume. So far, I've created Fat32 volume on /dev/sda4 (10 GB), copied these files there: initrd.img, kernel, ramdisk.img, system.sfs; and edited my /etc/grub.d/40_custom like this:

```
menuentry 'Remix OS Marshmallow' --class android-x86 {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='(hd0,gpt4)'
        linuxefi /kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=remix_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive DATA= CREATE_DATA_IMG=1 UVESA_MODE=1920x1080 verbose logo.showlogo=1
        initrdefi /initrd.img
}
```

It boots into it, gets to a Remix OS logo, and it's stuck there, just animating the logo over and over again. If I delete the "DATA= CREATE_DATA_IMG=1" it boots into the system, but any changes that I make (like installing something) get deleted after a reboot.

I've spent hours looking for a solution, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you boot into grub2 console and run ls / ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, combining two sources and a bit of my knowledge, here is a what you have to do, to get Remix OS running using Fedora 24, from your local ext4 volume, without any legacy bios requirement, using UEFI and GPT partitions only.

1. Create ext4 partiton on your hard drive (using gparted), you will install Remix OS on it later
2. Use Rufus (using Wine or Windows) to repartition your flash drive as GPT with UEFI support, and create a bootable ISO on it (using Rufus as well)
3. Boot from your flash drive on your laptop (be sure to disable secure boot)
4. Press 'e' key in GRUB that loaded from your flash drive[image: grub image]Replace the `SRC= DATA= CREATE_DATA_IMG=1` part with `INSTALL=1 DEBUG=` like this, but do not touch anything else. Press `ctrl + x` to run it
5. Choose your previously created ext4 partition, reformat it as ext4 again, **do NOT install GRUB, nor EFI GRUB2**
6. Install it on system directory as read-write, if you wish
7. Run your android, setup basic things, reboot back to Fedora
8. Open terminal, and run this command:`sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`
9. At the end of your file, add this:

   `menuentry 'Remix OS Marshmallow' --class android-x86 {
   insmod part_gpt
   insmod ext2
   set root='(hd0,gpt4)'
       linuxefi /android-2016-07-26/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=remix_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive SRC=/android-2016-07-26 UVESA_MODE=1920x1080 verbose logo.showlogo=1
       initrdefi /android-2016-07-26/initrd.img
   }`

   Yes, `ext2`, not `ext4`. Grub will throw an EFI error if you use `insmod ext4`.
10. Run this command to update your grub configuration: `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/Fedora/grub.cfg`
11. That's it, when you reboot, there should be a new entry, that will boot into your ext4 drive with Remix OS

[Source: XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/remix/remix-os/how-to-install-remix-os-alongside-t3352890)

Answer (score 0):

Do not create "**data.img**". Instead make a "**data**" folder where you copied your Remix files. Worked on **Debian and Debian based Linux**.
Not sure if it work for **fedora**. But grub is the same, I ***assume it should work***